# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native:packages:react-native:ReactAndroid:hermes-engine'

Tags: android, react-native, npm

When I try to run react native app in android then I get this error:

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDevelopmentDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:developmentDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native:packages:react-native:ReactAndroid:hermes-engine'.
> > Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/hass/App/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/build.gradle' (/Users/hass/.gradle/caches/8.0.1/scripts/aq46hk5izce44sxm4xg4lchjk).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 65**

I have spent a lot of days on it for searching and fixing it but I am not able to find any solutions. If someone knows how to fix it then please let me know. Thank you